# Linux Mint 13 Xfce - Use Super_L in multiple shortcuts

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the XfApplet for integrating the mintMenu into my Mint Xfce installation.
As shortcut I defined `Super_L` which works fine.
Additionally I want to define a shortcut `<Super_L>r` to execute `gnome-terminal`.
Unfortunately the `Super_L` keystroke gets interpreted and consumed early so that the mintMenu appears and types `r` into the search field.

*Is it possible to configure that both shortcuts `Super_L` and `<Super_L>r` work properly?*

**Edit:** This is how the mintmenu looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not entirely - the events seem to be activated on key-press (as opposed to key-release), hence the best you will likely be able to achieve is `Super_L` opening the menu, and if you don't let go of the key and press `r` being interpreted as `Super+r`, which would open your terminal (at least how this works for me).

Comment: So you created two shortcuts via the keyboard menu, right? How can I open the mint menu via the shell? I tried `mintmenu` but this simply spawns the menu button in the middle of the screen. Am I missing some parameter? Currently I only configured the menu shortcut in the panel's preferences not via the keyboard shortcut configuration..

Comment: @user1563 Yes, two shortcuts, but the one for plain `Super_L` is triggered always. I'm not really sure what mintmenu is - any chance `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu` might be what you are looking for? By the way, would it be suitable to use the `Menu` key to open the menu?

Comment: Since I'm using both Windows and Linux on different machines I want to configure the same shortcuts for convenience. The `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu` command opens the context menu of my mouse which is not what I'm looking for. I've added a screenshot of the mint menu. I changed the shortcut to `<Control>Super_L` which is less convenient but works at least. Thanks for your effort.